# How to identify if Angular toggle-switch toggle is clicked?

Tags: python, angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, try-catch

I am trying to define if Angular's toggle-switch is clicked or not using Selenium and Python tools.
When open a new form my input id has class `ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid`.

After clicked, it changes to `ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched`. But after a third click nothing changes.
After I click it and save the form, the class stays always `ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched` and remains the same after any change (even after disabling toggle and saving).
This is not a bug because changes are saved on server side.

Which CSS property should I look at to define what is changed?
Here is html code sample:

```
<div _ngcontent-c26="" class="form-group">
    <label _ngcontent-c26="" for="checked">Checked</label>
    <div _ngcontent-c26="" class="toggle-switch">
        <input _ngcontent-c26="" id="opened" name="checked" type="checkbox" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched">
            <label _ngcontent-c26="" for="checked"></label>
        </div>
        <span _ngcontent-c26="" class="form-control-helper"></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a few options and more research I found two solutions to test is a toggle/checkbox is checked.
**First**, by using .is_selected() Selenium's method:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=checkbox]").is_selected()
```

It returns True if a toggle is ON and False if it is OFF.

**Second**, I looked closely and CSS settings and found out that when a toggle is ON, :checked is added to it. So, you can use a boolean expression for this locator.
In Chrome's DevTools this attribute can be found in Properties tab, the name is `checked`. More details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51743810/chrome-devtools-not-showing-checked-or-checked-true-attribute-in-html-tag):

The locator for checked toggle will look like:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked
```

For unchecked:

```
input[type=checkbox]
```

Also, there is a **third** option which will work for many cases. For example, if a toggle changes its color, its property is also changed. So you can use:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=checkbox]").value_of_css_property("background-color") == "some color"
```

For example, place `"#fff"` (white) if you expect this CSS property to be white.

Answer (score 1):

### Form State and Input State

[AngularJS constantly updates](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp) the state of both the `<form>` and the `<input>` fields.

Input fields have the following states:

- `$untouched`: The field has not been touched yet
- `$touched`: The field has been touched
- `$pristine`: The field has not been modified yet
- `$dirty`: The field has been modified
- `$invalid`: The field content is not valid
- `$valid`: The field content is valid

These are the properties of the `<input>` field, and are either **`true`** or **`false`**.

Forms also have the following states:

- `$pristine`: No fields have been modified yet
- `$dirty`: One or more have been modified
- `$invalid`: The form content is not valid
- `$valid`: The form content is valid
- `$submitted`: The form is submitted

### This usecase

To validate the [Angular](https://angular.io/) toggle-switch state using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for [`visibility_of_element_located`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59644133/how-to-print-a-message-when-error-message-is-displayed-on-website-selenium/59646825#59646825) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Probing `ng-touched`:

  ```
  try:
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='opened' and @name='checked'][contains(@class, 'ng-touched')]")))
      print("Toggle Switch has been touched")
  except TimeoutException:
      print("Toggle Switch has not been touched")
  ```
- Probing `ng-dirty`:

  ```
  try:
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='opened' and @name='checked'][contains(@class, 'ng-dirty')]")))
      print("Toggle Switch has been touched")
  except TimeoutException:
      print("Toggle Switch has not been touched")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. I will try these options tomorrow.

Comment: @vitaliis Sounds great, let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestions and while researching found a few more good solutions.